# Sequences of を 「～を～を…」

Tags: parsing

> 幾つもの季節を、白い梅雨空を… 誰とも言葉を交わす必要もなく過ごした。

What does ～を～を mean? Also, とも usually is linked with a negative verb, so is 誰とも linked with 交わす, meaning "with someone" or it's linked with 必要もなく meaning "nobody"?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two を indicate the two objects of 過ごした, so that it means *(I) passed many seasons and white skies of rainy season*.

Putting phrases that way is a kind of rhetoric. It enumerates the phrases and emphasizes them. It can be used for other phrases.

- 危険なことはどこにでもある。道路に、学校に、家の中にも。 There are dangers everywhere. On the road, at school, or even at home.

---

Regarding 誰とも, as you understand, it constitutes a phrase up to 必要もなく: with no need to talk to anybody. It links with 言葉を交わす, but in the negative context (必要もなく).

Comment: In general, as far as I know, I could't use two を in a sentence and have two direct objects (*can I?*), but in that case, could I say it's the same as 幾つもの季節**と**白い梅雨空を...?

Comment: @BIG-95 Yes, you are right. It is the same as that.  This kind of construction is mostly for writing.

Comment: @BIG-95 Meaning-wise, it's the same, but your sentence is prosaic. The original sentence looks more dramatic, rhythmical and impressive to me.